# How to add text on mouse hover for p:toggleSwitch

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to add some text while tuning on/off the `p:toggleSwitch`.

```html
<p:toggleSwitch showTooltip="true"  
title="Enable/Disable Property"  
id="d_enable" onLabel="On" offLabel="Off"   
value="#{mybean.dEnabled}" />
```

I tried that but it's are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using the `ToggleSwitch` component. Instead, combine it with a `ToolTip` component like:

```html
<p:toggleSwitch id="myToggleSwitch" .../>
<p:tooltip for="myToggleSwitch" value="My toggleSwitch tip"/>
```

And, instead of guessing attributes, consider using an IDE which can assist you in using existing attributes, or simply read the [`ToggleSwitch` documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/toggleswitch).